# Power BI Custom Visuals

Tags: javascript, github, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a new custom visual in Power BI using Power BI Developer Tools. I am following the [Jon Gallant's Blog for Creating Power BI Custom Visual](http://blog.jongallant.com/2016/09/how-to-create-power-bi-custom-visual/). I had follow all the steps as is what mentioned in the blog, but I am getting an error of "**UNKNOWN RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**". This seem to be a javascript error which I am using. I don't know how to fix this issue.[image]

Can anyone help me getting this done.

Your help will be appreciated.

I got the code from [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonbgallant/PowerBI-visuals-liquidFillGauge/master/liquidFillGauge/src/liquidFillGauge.js)

Answer (score 1):

the problem described in this topic looks similar to your problem:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Feedback/Maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/td-p/40629

Comment: It happens when tsconfig.json contains *.js files in files section. It can be bug in template if you use old version of powerbi-visuals-tools